# How can I update a source file (with classes) in interactive python

Tags: python, interactive

Simple python question.

When in interactive mode, I'm test an imported file, let's say I use:

```
from foo import foo
```

But in the same time I edit the code. How can I update the script which is once loaded into interactive python? When I try to reimport it, nothing happens and I'm still on my old files.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
Ok, as I understand reload(modulename) works fine, but... What if I'm trying to reload a class with its methods? As it's written in documentation:

> If a module instantiates instances of a class, reloading the module that defines the class does not affect the method definitions of the instances — they continue to use the old class definition. The same is true for derived classes.

But there's no word how to update a class methods. Any idea?

The answer's here
[How to reload the code of a method of class object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670586/how-to-reload-the-code-of-a-method-of-class-object-in-python)

No more question as everything works fine now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at this question? 
[Reloading a changed python file in emacs python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816388/reloading-a-changed-python-file-in-emacs-python-shell)

Libraries in your python path can be easily updated with reload(modulename).

Comment: Thanks. I only searched for update, not thinking about reloading. I've edited the question, becouse there is still an issue with this.
EDIT: Found the answer, it's in main post.

Comment: That's awesome and powerful for testing! Thanks a lot for answer!