# emacs and python updating modules

Tags: python, emacs, emacs23, python-module

atm i'm using emacs to write some python code, so far it works quite fine except one problem that is really a bit annoying.

Always when I update something inside a self written module i reevaluate the buffer and the module in the python shell inside emacs doesn't get updated. i always have to end the python process and start it again to get the change. I figured out that emacs copies some things to a tmp dir to execute them, so i guess it has something to do with this.

Maybe someone out there had the same problem and solved it already so help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reload the module manually in the shell in order for it to take effect.

See the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) on the Python reload function

I asked a similar question which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816388/reloading-a-changed-python-file-in-emacs-python-shell)

Answer (score 2):

I found a **better** solution that needs no emacs config:

simply do

```
$ ipython profile create
```

that should create ipython profile in

```
$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
```

then put the following inside

```
c = get_config()
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.editor = 'emacsclient'
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = [
     'autoreload'
]

c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = []
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines.append('%load_ext autoreload')
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines.append('%autoreload 2')
```

then restart emacs. Now each time you save changes to file inside emacs - ipython would reload it **automatically**

and the following I have in my emacs config

```
;; ------------------
;; misc python config
;; ------------------
(company-mode -1)
(elpy-enable)
(elpy-use-ipython "ipython")
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython" python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt --pprint")
(setq python-check-command "flake8")
(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")
(setq elpy-rpc-python-command "python")
; https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython/issues/28
(setq python-shell-completion-native-enable nil)
```

if you want to see my full python config, it's [here](https://gist.github.com/dmitry-saritasa/104a6006eab6662cb2d6489dec8b1c0f)

Answer (score 0):

You can advise a python-mode.el function to get the desired effect (at least, if I am understanding your request properly). Put the following in your Emacs init file:

```
(defun py-reload-file (buf)
  "Reload buffer's file in Python interpreter."
  (let ((file (buffer-file-name buf)))
    (if file
        (progn
          ;; Maybe save some buffers
          (save-some-buffers (not py-ask-about-save) nil)
          (let ((reload-cmd
                 (if (string-match "\\.py$" file)
                     (let ((f (file-name-sans-extension
                               (file-name-nondirectory file))))
                       (format "if globals().has_key('%s'):\n    reload(%s)\nelse:\n    import %s\n"
                               f f f))
                   (format "execfile(r'%s')\n" file))))
            (save-excursion
              (set-buffer (get-buffer-create
                           (generate-new-buffer-name " *Python Command*")))
              (insert reload-cmd)
              (py-execute-base (point-min) (point-max))))))))

(defadvice py-execute-region
  (around reload-in-shell activate)
  "After execution, reload in Python interpreter."
  (save-window-excursion 
    (let ((buf (current-buffer)))
      ad-do-it
      (py-reload-file buf))))
```

Now, when you're in a python program, you can select a region of code, press <kbd>C-|</kbd> to evaluate the region and the python program will be reloaded (or imported if it wasn't previously loaded) in the Python interpreter buffer. The ENTIRE module will be reloaded, not just the region that was selected and you will be prompted to save the python file if it hasn't already been saved. Note that the caveats that were mentioned in the replies to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816388/reloading-a-changed-python-file-in-emacs-python-shell) still apply (e.g. - If you have class instances already created from the imported module, have instantiated other objects, etc, they won't be reloaded). General breakage may occur, so caveat emptor!).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Elpy as discussed [here](http://www.etedal.net/2019/05/emacs-as-python3-ide-in-mac.html).

Add the following to your Emacs configuration file:

```
(defun my-restart-python-console ()
  "Restart python console before evaluate buffer or region to avoid various uncanny conflicts, like not reloding modules even when they are changed"
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer "*Python*")
      (let ((kill-buffer-query-functions nil)) (kill-buffer "*Python*")))
  (elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-c") 'my-restart-python-console)
```

restart your Emacs run your code using `C-c C-x C-c`

In short, this code has the "if clause" for checking if *Python* buffer is open. This will help to be able to run `C-c C-x C-c` at any time of development even when there is no Python process already open. Another part is `kill-buffer-query-functions` which neglects the prompt for killing the *Python* buffer.

Comment: I like this solution but it comes the problem with the `if __name__ =="__main__"` statement. How I could restart the python shell before run the script with that line of code ?